# Exporting MS Access Charts to Word/Excel

Tags: ms-access, charts, export

I am amazed and dumbfounded to find out that a report generated in Microsoft Access will not include the charts I generated when exporting to Excel, Word or any other technology.

Has anyone found a work-around for this?  My user base needs to be able to copy/paste the generated reports (including graphics) into different status reports.  Copying/pasting does not seem to be possible directly from the Access report.

Comment: It is possible to cut and paste a chart from a form to Excel.

Comment: I don't see this as being a feasible option, unless I can generate and run entire reports within a form...

Comment: How does this relate to programming?

Comment: Ed, if you've ever tried to automate exporting Reports from MS Access, you'd know.

Answer (score 1):

I would really need more info to help you (which version of Access, How are you generating the graph, etc.).

Have you tried the "Publish It to Microsoft Word" or "Analyze it with Microsoft Excel" options from Print Preview?

One option your users have is to Alt-PrintScreen and paste it.

What I typically do is have users install [CutePDF Writer](http://www.cutepdf.com/) (it's free), and it lets them print to a PDF, which they then can send to whomever they want.

Comment: I am using Access 2003.  The graph lies in a group header.  Its source is a query.  The graph therefore gets printed once for every group of data.

All of the in-house publishing utilities that you mention export the data perfectly (rows of text, essentially) but completely ignore charts.

Comment: I am familiar with CutePDF and obviously with the PrintScreen/crop options, but I wanted to explore more elegant VBA solutions if at all possible.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is also something called snapshot, that can be further viewed by users and/or inserted in documents.

Answer (score 0):

install CutePDF Writer (it's free), and it lets them print to a PDF

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Access 2003 but in Access 2007 you go to the chart properties and set `Enabled` to `Yes`. Afterwards you can copy and paste the chart in Excel and/or Word.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I use a free screen capture utility for graphs generated in Access: get the graph on the screen, capture it, Paste or Paste Special into Word. Works well and fast, the only downside is losing resolution if you want the graph to be big (e.g. full page) in the Word document.